# How do I refer to an Area in my AreaPlan?

Tags: c#, revit-api

I am new to programming Revit-Apis and cannot finde a way to refer to my areas within my AreaPlans on a certain floor.
How do I do that?

Furthermore: How do I get the area of this certain Area and the rooms that lie within the area.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You must have list of Area then you can get what you want. To get list of Area use `FilteredElementCollector`, for example:

```
FilteredElementCollector allArea= newFilteredElementCollector(document).OfClass(typeof(Area));
```

then use LinQ or normal way to get List area

```
List<Area> listArea = allArea.ToElements().Select(x => (Area)x).ToList();
```